# android - Why my editText doesn't show?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi everyone needs help here.

I don't understand why my editText is not showing up. What Im so puzzled about is that I can see at my eclipse outline the editText.

Here are my codes:

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTESTER1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnTester1_text" 
/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTESTER1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/editTextHINT1"
    android:inputType="text"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**`strings.xml`**

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Android Tutorial</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="btnTester1_text">BUTTON TESTER</string>
<string name="editTextTester1_text">BUTTON TESTER</string>
<string name="editTextHINT1">Test</string>

</resources>
```

Im an absolute noob to android so please be patient. Please point out to me what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Show us the code where you're setting the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in your java file

Comment: @SpK Which one? MainActivity.java or R.java? Im not sure which file.

Comment: change the android:layout_width="fill_parent" of button to android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: Yes. @nick is right. Follow that one.

Comment: @AndroidMoron. Have you got the solution of my above comment

Comment: @nick Yup. I tried it but I really want my button width to expand. I did Akki's answer by changin android:orientation to vertical.

Comment: then do in button, android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="100dp" or any other size in dp you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have passed  `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` in your button and its taking whole width of your screen.Either change the `android:orientation="horizontal"`property of `LinearLayout` to vertical or `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Why the editText go underneath the button? I though it behaves like a browser.

Comment: if you change the orientation then it will go underneath if not and and just change the fill_parent to wrap_content then it will be side by side

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Change your orientation of LinearLayout to "vertical". Then they will be aligned vertically. 
This is happening because you are setting layout_width="fill_parent" in your Button which will fill the entire parent and thus will not show your EditText box.

Answer (score 0):

Let me thinks what exactly you want to do?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonTESTER1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnTester1_text" 
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTESTER1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/editTextHINT1"
        android:inputType="text"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```